# jQuery version in Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, version

All of our web pages contain:

```
<a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js" />
```

Through debugging I have found out that the jQuery version at runtime is actually *1.3.2*. My questions:

- Is the mentioned jquery.js indeed the one that is loaded?
- Where (if at all) can I find this library in the ear file?
- How can I upgrade to a higher version of jQuery, e.g. 3.3.1?

Answer (score 1):

To check the loaded version of the jquery use:

```
console.log(jQuery().jquery);
```

You can download the jquery from 'https://jquery.com/download/'

You can checkout the link 'https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp' to know the basic usage of jquery.

Comment: Thanks Jenish, your answers seem correct, but not exactly answers to my questions. Perhaps I can clarify: suppose that I do NOT want to change the line '<a4j:loadscript ...', and that I do have a proper file named 'jquery.js', where exactly do I place that file in my development environment. If it matters, the target webserver is Weblogic.